# How to update python googlefinance.client to 1.3.1?

Tags: python, ubuntu, google-finance

Python's googlefinance.client has stopped working after Google changed hostname for finance. I need to update googlefinance.client to 1.3.1.

How can I make my ubuntu upgrade googlefinance.client package to latest version?

So far, I tried:

```
sudo -H  pip install googlefinance.client googlefinance  --upgrade
```

But it only updates to 1.3.0. Any help?

Comment: 'does not work' is not a good description.  what errors did you get?

Comment: It updated only to version 1.3.0

Comment: well, that's the latest version, according to [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/googlefinance.client). 1.3.1 hasn't been released there yet, apparently